# Using TapControl header only for Excel-like application

Tags: .net, excel, layout, tabcontrol

I didn't find any better title for the description of my question, but I guess it's not such an usual approach:

I have an Excel-like application:

The GUI displays a grid, and there's a TabControl that shows the name of the different pages in the workbook.

When the TabPage header is clicked, the cells of this "page" are loaded and displayed in the grid.

I don't need another grid for that. I simply clear the grid and show the cells of this page in it, so the TabPages are superfluous to me.

However, I didn't find a way to keep the first TabPage activated.
When the user switches the tab, the grid of course disappears, and I have to re-parent it.

Is there an easier way to achieve what I would like to do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I do it like this:

I only use the header:

```
Me.TabControl1.Height = Me.TabControl1.DisplayRectangle.Height
```

I put the TabControl and the Grid into a TableLayoutPanel.

The 2 stay separate from each other.